# Array value is being persisted in mutlple instances of same component

Tags: ember.js

I have a component with property `arr:[]`, and i am pushing some value to this property by `this.get('arr').push('value one');` on init. If i use this component multiple times, the `arr`'s value is being persisted in all the other components. 
For ex: 
If i push some value on component init, `this.get('arr').push('value one')`.
If i use this component for one time it works fine, but for second use/instance, arr already has length 1 before i push to it.

Have a look at the console of this twiddle.

https://ember-twiddle.com/8a6527aebf829ee1876bccb5e3ee47b1

Is this behavior odd or it is supposed to work like this?

Comment: you can read http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/ for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is expected based on your example, but it is often, if ever, not desired. From the Ember Guides: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/

> - Arrays and objects defined directly on any `Ember.Object` are shared across all instances of that class.
> - To avoid this behavior, it is encouraged to initialize those arrays and object properties during `init()`. Doing so ensures each instance will be unique.

Recommend implementing the below in your example:

```
arr: null,

init() {
  this.set('arr', []);
  // .......
}
```

The below EmberTwiddle provides another "rough" example of the above: https://ember-twiddle.com/1006a702aa09c6d365bd1a46ca283059?openFiles=components.my-component.js%2C

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. If this was expected, then objects can be used to communicate between components directly(side-ways) without any parent. Isn't this against top-down paradigm of components?

Comment: This is expected due to the fact that this a result of how JavaScript works. Object and arrays are passed by a reference to their location in memory. Other posts do a far better job explaining this than I do here.

My basic explanation is that, when a new instance of the component is created, all following instances of the component will have a property that has the same reference as initial instance’s property. Regardless of the framework, this is something to watch for, as the framework designers may not deem it necessary to work around JavaScript’s inherit functionality.